# In MySQL how can I select based on a sub select "where" loop

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 databases.

1. `bundles` - all the information about the bundles.
2. `bundle_items` (`bundle_id`, `item_id`) - specifies which items are included in each bundle.
3. `items` - all the information about the items.

In one statement I need to search for 10 `bundles` that includes only items that are available.

`items` has a boolean column called `available`

If an item in a bundle is no longer available I obviously don't want anyone to see the bundle as it's invalid.

I also need to do a few other things such as count the total cost of all the items (can do this in php afterwards though so not really an issue)

What is the best way to achieve something like this? I am happy to change my database layout completely to find something that works.

Comment: Show the schema of the tables, and what you have already tried. Also, when you say "10" do you mean up to 10?

Comment: And  which 10. Random? Ordered?

Comment: Just a standard `SELECT * FROM bundles` search that I can sort however. `LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We take a simple 3 join between the three tables (the subquery) and use that as our WHERE clause. We can't LIMIT in the sub-query as that will limit to 10 order items, not 10 bundles.

The sub query will get all the bundles with at least one unavailable item and we excluded those using NOT IN in the outer select

Since you haven't posted the structure of your item and bundle tables I am assuming they have the respective ID columns

```
SELECT *
FROM  bundles
WHERE bundle_id NOT IN
                ( SELECT  b.bundle_id 
                  FROM    bundles b
                          JOIN bundle_items bi 
                              ON b.bundle_id = bi.bundle_id
                          JOIN items i
                              ON i.item_id = bi.bundle_id
                   WHERE  i.available = 0 )
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It still seems to be returning bundles that have unavailable items :( I feel like it's just checking for one that's available and then says yep this one has an available one it's good, instead of making sure all of the items are available. Is this possible or have I made a mistake copying it over?

Comment: Does the sub query alone return those? It would help if you could provide some example data (by adding create table and insert into statements to your question) and then showing which records are still included

Comment: I did miss the table alias from the select in the sub query which ive now added. I assume you added that to your query....

Comment: Updated. Please try now

Comment: I figured it out, I knew I was doing something wrong. Works flawlessly!

Comment: Was it a data issue?

Comment: in `bundles` and `items` the real id column is just `id` instead of `bundle_id` and `item_id`. Initially i had changed them to `id` but after you updated your answer i forgot to do so and just copy and pasted

Comment: Glad it's sorted. In future, include your tables schemas, test data and expected outputs as it means these sort of issues don't happen, plus it reduces ambiguity and ultimately you'll get more people willing to help :)